# Akka Actors Still Available After Stopped by PoisonPill

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm using akka to dynamically create actors and destroy them when they're finished with a particular job. I've got a handle on actor creation, however stopping the actors keeps them in memory regardless of how I've terminated them. Eventually this causes an out of memory exception, despite the fact that I should only have a handful of active actors at any given time.

I've used:

```
self.tell(PoisonPill, self)
```

and:

```
context.stop(self)
```

to try and destroy the actors. Any ideas?

Edit: Here's a bit more to flesh out what I'm trying to do. The program opens up and spawns ten actors.

```
val system = ActorSystem("system")
(1 to 10) foreach { x => 
  Entity.count += 1
  system.actorOf(Props[Entity], name = Entity.count.toString())
}
```

Here's the code for the Entity:

```
class Entity ()  extends Actor {
  Entity.entities += this
  val id = Entity.count
  import context.dispatcher
  val tick = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0 millis, 100 millis, self, "update")
  def receive = {
    case "update" => {
      Entity.entities.foreach(that => collide(that))
    }
  }
  override def postStop() = tick.cancel()
  def collide(that:Entity) {
    if (!this.isBetterThan(that)) {
      destroyMe()
      spawnNew()
    }        
  }
  def isBetterThan() :Boolean = {
    //computationally intensive logic
  }
  private def destroyMe(){
    Entity.entities.remove(Entity.entities.indexOf(this))
    self.tell(PoisonPill, self)
    //context.stop(self)
  }
  private def spawnNew(){
    val system = ActorSystem("system")
    Entity.count += 1
    system.actorOf(Props[Entity], name = Entity.count.toString())
  }  
}
object Entity {
  val entities = new ListBuffer[Entity]()
  var count = 0
}
```

Comment: can you show more code on where you create actor and how you stop actor? are these actors processing something infinitely?

Comment: Remember that it is not enough to send an actor a PoisonPill; the actor has to chew through all messages that preceded it. At the point where the PoisonPill message would actually be dispatched, the actor is killed.

Comment: http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

Comment: Its a really bad idea to create new `ActorSystem` as in the `def spawnNew`. You can use `context.system` instead. Both Entity.conv and Entity.entities are not safe. You should consider using a parent actor which manages these states and a child actor to do the computations.

Comment: @johny Yep. I'm working on that as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @AmigoNico, you pointed me in the right direction. It turns out that neither

```
self.tell(PoisonPill, self)
```

nor

```
context.stop(self)
```

worked for timely Actor disposal; I switched the line to:

```
system.stop(self)
```

and everything works as expected.

Comment: There is no difference between the last two possibilities, so your observation is flawed.